# Celery - Connection was forcibly closed by remote host

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have to process more than a million files, but after the process being running for nearly a minute i get this
`An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

This is my celeryconfig.py file

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
```

Here i am reading the files using glob and creating chunks, finally processing those chunks concurrently.

```
jobs = bulk_doc.chunks(zip(glob.iglob("C:/Data/" + '**/*.eml', recursive=True)), 1000).delay().get()
```

The code is being executed correctly however due to the connection being closed the results are lost and i wanna further use those results.

Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: Everything is on localhost, so permissions isn't a problem i think

Comment: What is the version of Celery and Kombu that you use?

Comment: celery 4.3
rabbitmq 2.5
kombu 4.6.4

Comment: We found 4.3.0 to be really buggy... We still use 4.2.1. I suggest you try 4.2.1 and see whether you have this problem. If you do not, then keep using that until 4.4.0 gets released.